# YouTube background does not work in Firefox and IE

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, video, background, youtube

I am building a website with a background video that works as intended in Chrome.
http://joshcosta.com.au/clients/tfv/

I don't know why it isn't working in IE and Firefox. Any ideas?

To add the video I used code from this site http://jellythemes.com/themes/solido/ (scroll down for the video)